# key_down & key_up commands in Selenium Webdriver (Python) suddenly won't work

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have been using Chrome Webdriver along with Selenium/Python to load and save some webpages.  It had been working fine.  Today Chrome kept crashing as soon as it opened so I downloaded the latest Chrome Webdriver which solved that issue.

However, the following lines did not seem to work any more:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

There was no error returned in the command prompt and all the other keyboard commands that did not use key_down/key_up worked correctly.

I have googled for a while but can't figure out why it is not working any more.  Thanks

Comment: "Not working anymore" isn't much of a problem description.  What is it supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  The code runs but there is no sign that the lines of code in my opening post exist, it just seems to skip past them.  The code should be pressing ctrl+s which should be opening the save window in Chrome but this does not happen.  Is there a different way to write those lines?

Comment: I updated to the latest version of Selenium but that hasn't helped either

Comment: after much troubleshooting I solved it by rewriting in the following way:  SendInput(Keyboard(VK_LCONTROL))
SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_S))
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_LCONTROL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))